# What is an independent subset of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, approximation-theory, matroids

I am reading a book about approximation algorithms. The book first defines an *independent system* and an *independent set* of a *family of subsets*. The definition about the *independent subset of a set* confuses me. That is,

**"For any $F\subseteq E$, a set $I\subseteq F$ is called a maximal independent subset of $F$ if no independent subset of $F$ contains $I$ as a proper subset."**

So, what is the **independent subset of $F$?** Can someone shows me an example?

Thanks very much!

Comment: What you are quoting explains the meaning of "maximal". The word "independent" has different meanings in different contexts and we don't know enough about yours. You should find a definition of "independent" earlier in the book you are studying from.

Comment: Maybe [Independent Sets](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndependentSet.html)

Comment: "Independent set" is part of the axiomatic definition and assumed structure of a matroid.

Comment: In the context of matroids, independent is just a label, a name, given to some collection of subsets. The collection has [some properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Independent_sets). You call the elements of that set, the independent subsets.

Comment: I do not understand what is the independent subset of a set in an independent system (or a matroid), as an *independent set* is defined based on the family of subsets. @Ehtan Bolker@user941248@plop

Comment: In the context of matroids, it is not a property inherent to the subsets themselves. You have to be told which subsets they want to be called "independent".

Comment: So, "the independent subsets of a set" means *some* independent sets *induced* from a set.  Is it right? @plop

Comment: It is hard to know for sure. Perhaps in your book they are modeling something specific. In general a matroid can be a set $X$ and we decide to call independent some of its subsets as long as the full collection that we call independent satisfies the properties above. For example, we could decide that all subsets of $X$ will be called independent. We could call independent only the empty set. Or if $X$ is a set of vectors of a vector space, we can call independent the subsets of vectors that are linearly independent.

Comment: Or if $X$ is a set of vertices of a graph, we could call independent the subsets of vertices that don't have edges between any of them.

Comment: @DuguHuo Without context this question can't be answered. Could you give us the context? Which book are you using? what area of mathematics is this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers and patience !! @plop

Comment: The book is <Design and Analysis of Approximation Algorithms> (Ding-Zhu Du, etc) and the related sentences are in Page~36 of Chapter~2.

Comment: In that same page they define it. Independent subsets are whichever they put in $\mathcal{I}$. Note that $\mathcal{I}$ is only required to have their property ($I_1$). They don't seem to ask for the other properties in the definition of matroids. They add the rest of the conditions later.

Comment: Yes, they do. But $\mathcal{I}$ is a family of subsets and the independent subsets are defined based on $\mathcal{I}$. However, $F$ is a set. So, as stated in the question, i am confused. And, i am confused how to generate or get **an indenpent set of a set** and what it looks like. ^-^ @plot

Comment: @DuguHuo It is best if you edit your question to include the book title and the definition of independent subsets. People should not have to read the comments to find out what the question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your question is about the definition of independent sets. The definition of an **independent system** in your book is given as:

> Let $E$ be a finite set and $\mathcal I$ a family of subsets of $E$. The pair $(E,\mathcal I)$ is called an *independent system* if
> $$(I_1)\quad I\in\mathcal I\text{ and }I'\subseteq I\Rightarrow I'\in\mathcal I$$
> Each subset of $\mathcal I$ is called an *independent subset*.

I believe this definition has a typo in it, or at the very least it is ambiguous. I think it should read (based on the definition of [independent subsets of matroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Independent_sets) and [this article about independence systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_system)):

> Each **element** of $\mathcal I$ is called an *independent subset* (of E).

or equivalently,

> A subset $I\subseteq E$ is called *independent* if $I\in \mathcal I$.

---

So $\mathcal I$ does not much more than putting a "label" on each subset of $E$, marking the difference between independent sets and non-independent sets.

So, if we have a subset $F\subseteq E$, we could ask which subsets of $F$ are independent. A maximally independent subset of $F$ is a subset $I\subseteq F$ such that $I\in \mathcal I$ (i.e. $I$ is independent) and such that no $I'\in\mathcal I$ exists with $I'\subseteq F$ for which $I\subsetneq I'$.

As an example, let:
\begin{align}
E&=\{1,2,3,4,5\}\\
\mathcal I&=\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\varnothing\}.\end{align} You can check that $(E,\mathcal I)$ is an independent system. As an example, $\{1,2\}$ is an independent subset of $E$, since $\{1,2\}\in \mathcal I$.

Now let $F=\{2,3,4\}\subseteq E$, then $\{2,3\}$ is a maximally independent subset of $F$. It is independent because $\{2,3\}\in \mathcal I$, and it is maximal, since if we add any other element of $F$ to $\{2,3\}$, it won't be independent anymore: the only candidate is $4$, and $\{2,3,4\}\notin\mathcal I$, thus $\{2,3,4\}$ is not independent.

On the other hand, the set $\{3\}$ is an independent subset of $F$, but not maximally independent, since $\{2\}$ is a proper subset of the independent set $\{2,3\}\subseteq F$

Note that there can be multiple maximally independent subsets of $F$. In this example $\{2,4\}$ is maximally independent as well.

Comment: Thanks for your wanderful explanation ! Now, I think it is clear about the independent set. @Vsotvep